# Spacy custom POS model for Hindi

Tags: spacy, part-of-speech

I recently worked on training a Part-of-Speech model for Hindi in Spacy. I got the model already trained but when analyzing any text, the `.pos_` attribute of any token always points to `X`. The fine-grained tags, `.tag_` - which were the ones the model was trained with - are correct though.

The mapping between this fine-grained tags and the "universal" tags (VERB, NOUN, ADJ, etc) is found in the `spacy/lang/hi/tag_map.py` file.

```
Lemma यूरोप, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NNP
Lemma के, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PSP
Lemma जिन, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: DEM
Lemma राजनीतिक, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: JJ
Lemma दलों, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma को, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PSP
Lemma व्यवस्था, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma ,, Lemmatized: False, POS: SYM, TAG: SYM
Lemma राजनेताओं, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma और, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: CC
Lemma मीडिया, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma द्वारा, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PSP
Lemma अति, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: INTF
Lemma दक्षिणपंथी, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma कहा, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VM
Lemma जाता, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VAUX
Lemma है, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VAUX
Lemma (, Lemmatized: False, POS: SYM, TAG: SYM
Lemma परन्तु, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: CC
Lemma मेरी, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PRP
Lemma ओर, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NST
Lemma से, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PSP
Lemma सभ्यतावादी, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NNP
Lemma कहा, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VM
Lemma जाता, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VAUX
Lemma है, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VAUX
Lemma ), Lemmatized: False, POS: SYM, TAG: SYM
Lemma उनकी, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PRP
Lemma आलोचना, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma उनकी, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PRP
Lemma भूलों, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma और, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: CC
Lemma अतिवादिता, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NN
Lemma के, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PSP
Lemma कारण, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: PSP
Lemma की, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VM
Lemma जाती, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: VAUX
Lemma है|, Lemmatized: False, POS: X, TAG: NNPC
```

Investigating a little bit I found out that the reason the `.pos_` has this `X` value is because in the generated `lang_model/tagger/tag_map` binary file, all of its keys point to `101` which is the "code" assigned to the Part-of-Speech `X`, which is `Other`.

I deduce it is generating the keys pointing to `101` because there's no information at how it should map each of the provided tags from the dataset to the "universal" ones. The thing is, I can provide a `tag_map.py` in the definition of my `Hindi(Language)` class, but when passing a text through the pipeline, it will eventually use the tag map defined in the `tagger/` directory created with by the output of the `train` command.

Here's a link which will clarify what I'm explaining:  https://universaldependencies.org/tagset-conversion/hi-conll-uposf.html

The first item of the first column (`CC`, `DEM`, `INTF`, etc) are the ones provided to the model. The universal tags are the ones from the second column.

My question is, where should I define the tag_map to overwrite the one generated by the `spacy train` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `tag_map.py` to `spacy/lang/hi/` and tell the default model (which is what gets loaded with `spacy train hi`) to load it. It sounds like you already have a `tag_map.py`, but if not, you can see examples for any of the languages that have provided spacy models, like:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/tag_map.py

Import the tag map and add it to the `HindiDefaults` in `spacy/lang/hi/__init__.py` to load the tag map:

```
from .tag_map import TAG_MAP

class HindiDefaults(Language.Defaults):
    tag_map = TAG_MAP
```

I think you could also modify the tag map in `nlp.vocab.morphology.tag_map` on-the-fly after initializing the blank model before you starting training, but I don't think there's any easy way to do it with command-line options to `spacy train`, so that would require a custom training script.

You can use `spacy debug-data hi train.json dev.json` to make sure the settings worked, since it will show warnings for any tags in your training data that aren't in the tag map.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I already figured out and it is as you suggested, I had to place it on the source code of Spacy. Now I have another problem, my custom NER is not detecting any entities. I checked that the NER pipeline is loaded and it contains the tags which I trained it with. Any idea what I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: @Adrián Hi, I am trying to add POS of a specific domain to an existing model in Portuguese, from a * .conllu file (that is, it takes into account the context of the sentence), I am not finding information on the internet (I found for NER but not for POS), if your script is freely available could you please share it? Thanks.